# $.post not sending a variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been working with the "Bootstrap Selectpicker plugin", but to custimize it I need the ID of the event(In a calender), when i press it. The variable only exists in Javascript, but i need it in PHP..

I have tried something like this:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
  element.bind('dblclick', function() {
    $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
    $.post("calender/variabler.php", {eventid: event.id});
    $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
    $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
    $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
  });
},
```

But it dosen't work. You can see alle my Javascript coding here: https://pastebin.com/crqPXvtH and this is my "variabler.php":

```
<?php
$eventidcalender = $_POST['eventid'];
?>
```

Comment: $.post("calender/variabler.php", {eventid: event.id});

Review name of folder, maybe this is the error 'calender' instead 'calendar'

Comment: It is the correct location of the file..

Comment: Any other ideas?